# Column not found in SQL Laravel Query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this Query

```
$query= Book_detail::groupBy('ddate', 'book_details.room_id')
->join('books', 'book_id', '=', 'books.id')
->join('rooms', 'book_details.room_id', '=', 'rooms.id')
->selectRaw('sum(books.room_qty) as sum, ddate, book_details.room_id, 
 rooms.room_qty - sum(books.room_qty) as stock')
->whereRaw('stock >= 5');
```

but it got error

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stock' in 'where clause'
```

I think because column 'stock' is additional column. So i try change a bit like this

```
  ->whereRaw('stock >= 5');
```

to

```
   ->whereRaw('rooms.room_qty - sum(books.room_qty) >= 5');
```

but that didnt work because whereRaw cannot accept sum. other way is using havingRaw,

```
   ->whereRaw('rooms.room_qty - sum(books.room_qty) >= 5');
```

But using havingRaw I got error:

```
   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rooms.room_qty' in 'having clause'
```

as I read in other case, I think i can use sub-query. But to be honest I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try `havingRaw('stock >= 5')`?

Comment: tried but no success, unknows column :(